# PHP preg_match: linking single or multiple images via class function

Tags: php, image, class, preg-match, switch-statement

Hey fellow programmers,

What I'm trying to accomplish is a dynamic way to source images from a directory with the use of a class `image`.

I'm stuck at supplying an exact string which returns a match but when trying to echo `"` with the returned match if the whole string is not provided then the image is linked with a partial string plus the extension.

```
<?php $image = new image; ?>
```

calling the class function with:

```
<?php $image -> get_image('this_string_1',''); ?>
```

The Image directory contents

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/;'?>

this_string_1.png

this_string_2.png

this_string_3.png
```

The class:

```
<?php 
class image{
    function get_image($name,$class){
    if(strlen($class)==0){ $class="default"; }
    ##@@[ Checks the type of image
    global $doc_root,$html_path;
    if($handle = opendir($doc_root.'/images/')){
        while(false !==($value = readdir($handle))){
            if($value !== '..' && $value!=='.'){
                $extention;
                $ext_jpeg = substr($value,-3);
                    if($ext_jpeg=='jpg'){
                        $extention=".jpg";
                    }
                $ext_png = substr($value,-3);
                    if($ext_png=='png'){
                        $extention=".png";
                    }
                $ext_gif = substr($value,-3);
                    if($ext_gif=='gif'){
                        $extention='.gif';
                    }
                }
            switch($extention){
                case '.jpg':
                if(preg_match("/$name/",$value,$result)){
                    foreach($result as $jpg){
                        echo '<img class="'.$class.'" src="'.$html_path.'/images/'.$jpg.'.jpg">';
                        }
                    }
                break;
                case '.png':
                if(preg_match("/$name/",$value,$result)){
                    foreach($result as $png){
                        echo '<img class="'.$class.'" src="'.$html_path.'/images/'.$png.'.png">';
                        }
                    }
                break;
                case '.gif':
                if(preg_match("/$name/",$value,$result)){
                    foreach($result as $gif){
                        echo '<img class="'.$class.'"src="'.$html_path.'/images/'.$gif.'.gif">';
                        }
                    }
                break;

                }
            }   
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish something like this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

As per Martins advice.
I have removed the if and switch statements and replaced it with "substr" in the second if statement.

```
<?php 
class image{
    function get_image($name,$class){
    if(strlen($class)==0){ $class="default"; }
    global $doc_root,$html_path;
    if($handle = opendir($doc_root.'/images/')){
        while(false !==($value = readdir($handle))){
            if($value !== '..' && $value!=='.' && substr($value, 0, -4)==$name){

                echo '<img src="'.$html_path.'/images/'.$value.'">';

                }
            }   
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I do not see much point of your sequence of `if` statements to assign `$extention`. Why don't you just do `$extention = substr($value,-4)`?

2) The `switch($extention)` has to be inside the `if($value !== '..' && $value!=='.')`

3) What are you trying to achieve by the `preg_match`?

If you just want to match name completely, just do `substr($value, 0, -4) == $name`. Well this rely on extension having 3 characters, what's not perfect, but you rely on that already.

Comment: Martin thank you i have restructured the code reflecting your examples. Many thanks.